# Heatmap correlation plot half with values number and half color map in seaborn

Tags: python, heatmap, correlation, seaborn

In the previous versions of seaborn (<0.7) it was present the function *corrplot()*, which allowed to plot a correlation matrix such that half of the matrix is numeric and the other half is a color map. Now, seaborn (0.7.1) has just the *heatmap()* function, that doesn't have this function directly. Is there a way to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 4):

I have spend some time to do it, basically it require to overlap two heatmaps, where one makes use of a mask to cover half of the matrix. A code example is showed below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.pylab import *

arr_name = ['D','S','P','E','C','KW','K','EF']
data = np.random.randn(8,8)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=arr_name)
labels = df.where(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool))
labels = labels.round(2)
labels = labels.replace(np.nan,' ', regex=True)

mask = np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool)
ax = seaborn.heatmap(df, mask=mask, cmap='RdYlGn_r', fmt='', square=True, linewidths=1.5)
mask = np.ones((8, 8))-mask
ax = seaborn.heatmap(df, mask=mask, cmap=ListedColormap(['white']),annot=labels,cbar=False, fmt='', linewidths=1.5)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

The final result is following:
[image]